# Join table t1 and t2, only keep one column of t1

Tags: sql

Let's say we have two tables:

- `t1: (c1a, c3, c4, c5 ... c1000)`
- `t2: (c1b, c2)`

I want to add `c2` to `t1` based on matching `c1a`/`c1b` values. `c1a` and `c1b` have the same values, I just named them differently to avoid ambiguity. I do a join:

`select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 as t3`

Now `t3` will have the data I need, but it will look like so:

`t3: (c1a, c1b, c2, c3, c4, c5 ... c1000)`

This is correct in the sense that it has all the columns I want. However, it has an extra column I don't want - because I did `select *` initially, all the columns from both tables are included. What if I don't want the extra columns?

- I could manually specify the columns I want: `select c1a, c2, c3, c4, c5 ... c1000 from t1 left join ...` The problem is obvious.
- I could separately remove `c1b`. This seems hacky; I feel like this should be doable in one statement.

Is there a SQL expression that means something like `select all columns except for x, y from ...`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: No.  You need to specify all the columns you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using Redshift, but I am more interested in generalizable SQL solutions rather than possible Redshift-specific stuff so I decided not to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

If the only duplicate columns are coming from the `join`, then the `using` clause will help:

```
select *
from t1 left join
     t2 
     using (c1);
```

Note:  Not all databases support `using` (although it is SQL standard).

If almost all the columns come from one of the tables, you can get those using `*` and the rest explicitly:

```
select t1.specialcol, t2.*
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

There do exist databases that have an `except` clause for this purpose.  But it is not very common.